# For Each Loop slow for adding data to Listbox in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, loops, foreach, listbox

I use the following loops to add data to a Listbox, if the value in a certain range includes "(FS)".

The search range is defined as `AllAreas(12)`. Option buttons on the Userform define which of the 12 areas to search, these are defined by three Integers: `Upr`, `Lwr` and `Idx`.

`Plybooker` is a String from a Combobox value. If this is not blank then the data entered in to the Listbox is filtered with this in mind, hence the `If`, `ElseIf` statement.

The code works absolutely fine, but is **very slow** when searching the full range (i.e. when all 12 ranges contained within `AllAreas` are searched).

I need an alternative method for adding the data to the Listbox that is much faster than my For Each Loop. Any suggestions welcome!

Many thanks

```
Public Sub PlybookListboxAll()

Dim Plybooker As String
Plybooker = Plybooks.ComboBox1.Value

Dim Upr As Integer, Lwr As Integer
If Plybooks.OptionButton12.Value = True Then
    Lwr = 0
    Upr = 12
End If

If Plybooker = "" Then
        For Idx = Lwr To Upr
            For Each MyCell In AllAreas(Idx).Cells
                If InStr(1, MyCell.Value, "(FS)") > 0 Then 'And IsNumeric(MyCell.Offset(0, 6).Value) Then
                    Plybooks.ListBox1.AddItem
                    Plybooks.ListBox1.List(i, 0) = MyCell.Offset(, -1).Value
                    Plybooks.ListBox1.List(i, 1) = MyCell.Value
                    Plybooks.ListBox1.List(i, 2) = MyCell.Offset(, 2).Value
                    Plybooks.ListBox1.List(i, 3) = MyCell.Offset(, 3).Value
                    Plybooks.ListBox1.List(i, 5) = MyCell.Offset(, 8).Value
                    If IsNumeric(MyCell.Offset(, 6).Value) = True Then
                        Plybooks.ListBox1.List(i, 4) = CInt(MyCell.Offset(, 6).Value)
                    Else: Plybooks.ListBox1.List(i, 4) = "TBC"
                    End If
                    i = i + 1
                End If
            Next MyCell
        Next Idx

ElseIf Plybooker <> "" Then
        For Idx = Lwr To Upr
            For Each MyCell In AllAreas(Idx).Cells
                If InStr(1, MyCell.Value, "(FS)") > 0 And MyCell.Offset(0, 2).Value = Plybooker Then 'And IsNumeric(MyCell.Offset(0, 6).Value)
                    Plybooks.ListBox1.AddItem
                    Plybooks.ListBox1.List(i, 0) = MyCell.Offset(, -1).Value
                    Plybooks.ListBox1.List(i, 1) = MyCell.Value
                    Plybooks.ListBox1.List(i, 2) = MyCell.Offset(, 2).Value
                    Plybooks.ListBox1.List(i, 3) = MyCell.Offset(, 3).Value
                    Plybooks.ListBox1.List(i, 5) = MyCell.Offset(, 8).Value
                    If IsNumeric(MyCell.Offset(, 6).Value) = True Then
                        Plybooks.ListBox1.List(i, 4) = CInt(MyCell.Offset(, 6).Value)
                    End If
                    i = i + 1
                End If
            Next MyCell
        Next Idx
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Create an array and assign it the `List` property of the listbox. `AddItem` is very slow.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I am new to arrays, can you give me any further guidance as to how this might work? I will come up with something but am struggling to work this one out, just need a nudge in the right direction!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a sample of using arrays inside the loop that you were using to populate the listbox (note the array is flipped as you can only change the last dimension when resizing it at the end, so you then use the Column property to flip it back into the control):

```
    Dim myArray()
    ReDim myArray(5, 1000) '1000 is a number intended to be larger than the amount of data you expect
    For Idx = Lwr To Upr
        For Each MyCell In AllAreas(Idx).Cells
            If InStr(1, mycell.value, "(FS)") > 0 Then 'And IsNumeric(MyCell.Offset(0, 6).Value) Then
                myarray(0, i) = MyCell.Offset(, -1).Value
                myarray(1, i) = MyCell.Value
                myarray(2, i) = MyCell.Offset(, 2).Value
                myarray(3, i) = MyCell.Offset(, 3).Value
                myarray(5, i) = MyCell.Offset(, 8).Value
                If IsNumeric(MyCell.Offset(, 6).Value) = True Then
                    myarray(4, i) = CInt(MyCell.Offset(, 6).Value)
                Else: myarray(4, i) = "TBC"
                End If
                i = i + 1
            End If
        Next MyCell
    Next Idx
    If i > 0 then
       Redim Preserve myarray(5, i - 1)
       Plybooks.ListBox1.Column = myarray
    End If
```

It would likely be a lot more efficient to load your source ranges into an array and process that, rather than  but I leave that to you. :)

(Note: this is air code so I may have missed something, but it was too long to put into a comment)

Comment: Thanks Rory, very helpful. This will take me a while to understand. I am getting a run time error saying "array already dimensioned" at line: `ReDim Preserve myArray(5, i - 1)`

Comment: @Faminebob I've edited the code, so hopefully should run ok now.

Comment: Hi @Rory - now getting "subscript ot of range" on line: `myArray(i, 0) = MyCell.Offset(, -1).Value`. I tried upping the `1000` to `10000`, which definitely covers my data size, but still throwing the same error.

Comment: @Faminebob Sorry - that was daft of me. I forgot to switch the row and column indices round there - will amend it.

Comment: many thanks this is now a much faster solution than `AddItem`. I am getting a runtime error though when the result of the `If` statement returns no data to be entered in to the Listbox, which is sometimes the case. This is giving me "Subscript out of range" at line: `ReDim Preserve myArray(5, i - 1)`.

Comment: @Faminebob I've added an If block that should handle that.